# Unsubsribe from a topic and define a new one runtime(C++)

Tags: ros, c++, topics

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i'd like to change the name of the topic which I read data from during runtime.
..that seems not to be feasible.
my idea now is the following: if a certain condition is satisfied I unsubscribe from a topic and define a new subscriber (with a new topic) that uses the same callback used by the old subscriber.
Is this feasible?
how can i unsubscribe from a topic?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/64813/unsubsribe-from-a-topic-and-define-a-new-one-runtime(c++)/) by [mateo_7_7](https://answers.ros.org/users/4299/mateo_7_7/) on ROS Answers with karma: 90 on 2013-06-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you subscribe to a new topic using the same callback and store the result in the same [Subscriber object](http://ros.org/doc/groovy/api/roscpp/html/classros_1_1Subscriber.html#details), storing that new value in the original variable should unsubscribe the other topic.

**EXAMPLE**: *untested, probably buggy*

```
class Reader
{
public:
  Reader(ros::NodeHandle node)
  {
    node_ = node;
    // subscribe to original topic
    topic_ = node.subscribe("first_topic", 10,
                            &Reader::callback, (Reader *) this);
  }

private:
  void callback(const std_msgs::String::ConstPtr &msg)
  {
    if (msg->data == "switch")
      {
        // subscribe to other topic
        topic_ = node_.subscribe("next_topic", 10,
                                 &Reader::callback, (Reader *) this);
      }
    else
      {
        // log message from current topic
        ROS_INFO_STREAM(msg->data);
      }
  }

  // class variables
  ros::NodeHandle node_;
  ros::Subscriber topic_;           // current topic subscription
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "your_node");
  ros::NodeHandle node;
  Reader read(node);
  ros::spin();
  return 0;
}
```

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2013-06-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mateo_7_7](https://answers.ros.org/users/4299/mateo_7_7/) on 2013-06-11**:
so changing the topic name (changing the string) runtime should be sufficient to unsubscribe from a topic and start subscribing from another...but, as i understood, it's not allowed in ROS actually.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-06-12**:
Just make a new subscription in the same we you did the original one.

**Comment by [mateo_7_7](https://answers.ros.org/users/4299/mateo_7_7/) on 2013-06-12**:
..can you post an example please?